# How to remove the trailing slash from a variable which defines a directory from a time test output

Tags: bash, delete, slash

Ubuntu 16.04

Even thou the output of for `client in */; do` doesn't produce a trailing slash, the trailing slash appears if I echo the variable $client while performing a time test on the file, within the loop.

```
cd "$wDir"
for client in */; do
   cd "$wDir"/"$client";

   #-- check to see if any .csv files exists
   if ls *.csv &>/dev/null; then
      for csvfile in *.csv; do
         if test $(find "$csvfile" -mmin +2880); then
            echo "$client has files older than 2 days ..." >> "staleFtpAccts"
         fi
      done
   fi
done
```

When I execute the script, a / is placed after the $client variable like so:

```
root@me /home/frank # bash script.sh
Start ...
000029_000020/ has files older than 2 days ...
#--
Finished ...

Start ...
000033_000040/ has files older than 2 days ...
#--
Finished ...

Start ...
000033_000041/ has files older than 2 days ...
#--
Finished ...

Start ...
000033_000042/ has files older than 2 days ...
#--
Finished ...

Start ...
000033_000043/ has files older than 2 days ...
#--
Finished ...
```

This is the result I am after ...

```
root@me /home/frank # bash script.sh
Start ...
000029_000020 has files older than 2 days ...
#--
Finished ...

Start ...
000033_000040 has files older than 2 days ...
#--
Finished ...

Start ...
000033_000041 has files older than 2 days ...
#--
Finished ...

Start ...
000033_000042 has files older than 2 days ...
#--
Finished ...

Start ...
000033_000043 has files older than 2 days ...
#--
Finished ...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this [posix](/questions/tagged/posix) *parameter expansion* :

```
echo "${client%/}"
```

so

```
echo "${client%/} has files older than 2 days ..."
```

> Parameter Expansion expands parameters: `"$foo"`, `"$1"`. You can use it to perform string or array operations: `"${file%.mp3}"`, `"${0##*/}", "${files[@]: -4}"`. They should **always** be quoted. See: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073 and "Parameter Expansion" in man bash. Also see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe.

Comment: Well appreciated Gilles.